# jquery waiting for .ajax() to complete within .each() iteration

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

Ive a jquery function that obtains text from all nodes of a particular class using the jquery **.each()** selector:

```
function get_text()
            {
              $(".my_class").each(function () 
              {
                $this = $(this);
                node_text = $this.text();
                console.log(node_text);
              })
            }
```

That works as expected. Next, I want to send the text to a php script using **.ajax()** :

```
function get_php_text(node_text)
            {
               let url = `myphp.php?string_text=${node_text}`;
                 $.ajax(
                      {
                        url: url,
                        success: function(result)
                          { 
                            console.log(result);
                          }
                      });
            }
```

That function also works as expected.

When I run the following:

```
function get_text()
            {
              $(".my_class").each(function () 
              {
                $this = $(this);
                node_text = $this.text();
                get_php_text(node_text);
              })
            }
```

I run into a problem as **get_php_text()** is not waiting for each **.each()** iteration to complete.

How can I rewrite the **get_text()** function so that it waits for the **get_php_text(**) to return before going to the next iteration?

Comment: You could use a closure for this.

Comment: could you provide an example?

Comment: @h b Take a look at my answer, I have included some samples which (I hope) you'll find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit: Removed a promise as pointed out $.each doesn't support it.

Another example is using closures, but it should be used if you want to send data every time an iteration occurs in $.each.

```
function get_text() {
    function SampleClosure(node_text) {
        let url = `myphp.php?string_text=${node_text}`;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    }

    $(".my_class").each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        node_text = $this.text();
        SampleClosure(node_text);
    })
}
```

So, what happens above is, every element, the text is extracted and passed to a Closure which is an expression that can reference variables within its scope when it was first declared. So even if you change the passed variable before the Ajax call is sent, it'll still use the old passed text and function will execute. I like to (which is wrong) think of it as creating an instance of a function with passed data which once completed is taken care of by GC, and within the loop, multiple instances of the function are created within their own memory allocation. As I said, this is how I see it, and what I said might be wrong, but theoretically this is how the process appears to me and works.

Comment: The first option won't work for his question, because it doesn't call `get_php_text` for every item in the each loop. The each loop itself doesn't support `.promise()` and doesn't need it either, because it is synchronous. It's that asynchonous ajax call that should happen inside the loop that is the issue.

Comment: The second option will also not work. That is basically the same thing that he had already. `SampleClosure()` is called multiple times, but the ajax requests that are triggered by that function will not all complete in the order that they were called, which is the exact problem he is trying to solve.

Comment: @vi5ion You're wrong about the second option. Second option will work fine for what you're saying. You're passing data in, by value not by reference. Thats the reason for a closure. I personally use closures to make ajax calls within a loop inside my Node applications. Also he never stated they need to be completed in an order they were called in, his problem is the fact that the ajax calls are overwritten each time, so he ends up with (most likely) just one call (the last iteration) being made.

Comment: @vi5ion You're however right about the first option, it is synchronous and .promise isn't supported. Adding on to my comment... the ajax in second option will execute just fine too. It'll be allocated and executed no matter how many times you call the function.

Comment: Yes you're right, it does work. Sorry, that was a poor choice of words on my part :) But I really do think he wants them to be executed in order. Hence why his question states "..so that it waits for the get_php_text() to return before going to the next iteration". It's not that his original code doesn't work, but it doesn't wait for every iteration to complete before going to the next.

Comment: @vi5ion His original code doesn't work and it won't. Ajax requests are async, meaning the whole iteration will finish before the Ajax call is completed. Therefore, the ajax call will be overwritten multiple times and only the last element of the iteration will be sent. This is exactly the reason for this question (as seen by me) he wants to make sure the item is sent before iterating the next item, which makes sense. My code not only works as expected but also won't hung the application like waiting for ajax calls to finish within the actual iteration process.

Comment: @vi5ion If you put a condition inside the iteration to wait with the iteration until Ajax is completed (Basically making the Ajax synchronous) then the application will freeze (which you should avoid). Say you're iterating 20 elements, each elements takes 1 second to complete the request, the application will freeze for 20 seconds before continuing. A Closure will execute the Ajax request async, solving all issues. Also why the down vote if you don't mind me asking? I believe those are all relevant and valid points, and this should be the only or one of very few correct answers.

Comment: Of course that's making ajax synchronous and kind of defeating its purpose, but that is how I interpreted his question. I'm not saying that is ideal or a situation that you'd want. We both have a different interpretation of his question and offered two different solutions for two different cases. I didn't downvote btw, just upvoted to negate the -1.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it so that the iterating is done inside the success handler of your ajax call, by making `get_php_text()` recursive. This way the next iteration will only occur after the previous one has finished its ajax request.

```
function get_text() {
  let node_text_array = [];
  $(".my_class").each(function() {
    node_text_array.push($(this).text());
  });
  get_php_text(node_text_array);
}  

function get_php_text(node_text_array) {
  if (node_text_array.length>0) {
    let node_text = node_text_array.splice(0,1);
    let url = 'myphp.php?string_text=${node_text}';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        get_php_text(node_text_array);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it does? `let node_text = node_text_array.splice(0,1);` should decrease the size of the array on every iteration, so it should eventually be empty, at which point it no longer gets past `if (node_text_array.length>0)`.

Comment: I've made a fiddle that seems to work just fine (obviously without the ajax request): https://jsfiddle.net/zuqkf842/

Comment: yes i can see that it works but it seems the ajax may still be creating a problem and the fiddle does not simulate the ajax call

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Because I just tried it with ajax request on a local test project and it also works there. I did notice the quotes around the `url` were not proper quotes so I edited that. Not sure if that was the issue though.

Comment: no errors, it works fine insofar as executing the php and returning the correct result but does not stop looping.

Comment: Could you add `console.log(node_text_array.length)` at the start of `get_php_text`? This number should decrease on each call, so either it is not decreasing for you or never reaching 0.

Comment: it goes to 0 and starts again from the beginning

Comment: that sounds like you're doing multiple calls to `get_text`